# How do you create a before action for one specific page in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two controllers: pages_controller and charges_controller

pages_controller just has:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
    def show
        render template: "pages/#{params[:page]}"
    end
end
```

charges_controller has basic stripe info to accept charges

my routes.rb has a root set to my home page and:

```
get "/:page" => "pages#show"
```

I have about 8 html files in views/pages/

I want one and only one of those pages, "products.html.erb" to have a before_action authenticate user!

If I add a before action to the pages controller, it affects every page. Need some tips, new developer.

Comment: if you find there are some solution from answers below it will be nice to follow up with check the correct one / some comments

Answer (score 1):

You can single out the action that renders "products.html.erb" using `before_action`. If it is only rendered in your show action, it would look like:

```
before_action :authenticate_user, only: [:show]
```

You can add as many routes as you want in there like:

```
before_action :authenticate_user, only: [:show, :create, :destroy]
```

[Here](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods/before_action) are the docs for it.

Comment: @hayden did you figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom private method which verifies the value for the `params[:page]` param, and depending if this is the one which you want or not to restrict then apply the devise `authenticate_user` before filter only in the `show` method, something like:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :custom_authenticate_user!, only: :show

  # remains equal
  def show
    render template: "pages/#{params[:page]}"
  end

  private

  # only if params[:page] equal 'bla' then use the authenticate_user! 
  def custom_authenticate_user!
    authenticate_user! if params[:page] == 'bla'
  end
```

Also this is an easier way, just to use `if` and the `only` option in order to check the params and make it work, without having to create a new method:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: :show, if: -> { params[:page] == 'bla' }
```

Comment: can we add before_action for normal methods like non-routes classes?

Comment: You can work around ActiveSupport callbacks if you need to, see [Karol Bąk](https://kukicola.io/posts/useful-active-support-features-you-may-not-have-heard-of/) post to get an idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
    def show
        if "#{params[:page]}" == "product"
          your action here
        end
        render template: "pages/#{params[:page]}"
    end
end
```

before_action inside controller usually for "same code" between new/show/edit/update, since you just need special code for one page I think you just need if command before render it

Answer (score 0):

add `before_action` with `only:` option to pass an array of actions you want to apply the filter. There is another option you can use `skip:` to pass an array of actions if you want that filter to apply to all the actions except the action names you want to skip

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:show]

  def show
    render template: "pages/#{params[:page]}"
  end
end
```